# Induced Euler short exact sequence on wedge product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-space, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

From any short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow H\longrightarrow 0$, we can construct the following induced exact sequence on wedge product (following [apendix A](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01359.pdf)):

$$ 0\longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^2 F\longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^2 G\longrightarrow (F\otimes H)\oplus\bigwedge\nolimits^2 H\longrightarrow 0 $$

I'm now trying yo apply this to the Euler short exact sequence:

$$ 0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(+1)^{\oplus n+1}\longrightarrow\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\longrightarrow 0 $$

In that case we would have:

$$ 0\longrightarrow\bigwedge\nolimits^2\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\longrightarrow\bigwedge\nolimits^2\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(+1)^{\oplus n+1}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^2\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\right)\oplus\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\longrightarrow 0 $$

My question is if this last short exact sequence makes sense, in particular, if $\bigwedge\nolimits^2\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ really makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, it's just zero.

Comment: @KReiser what is zero?

Comment: $\bigwedge^2 \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}=0$.

Comment: can you tell me more or last why?

Comment: It's zero for the same reason that $\bigwedge^2$ of a 1-dimensional vector space (or a rank-1 free module over a ring) is zero. Check the definitions and compute.

Comment: (In fact, the statement that the 2nd exterior power of a rank-1 free module is zero proves the claim for sheaves by going to stalks.)

Comment: excellent, thak you very much

Comment: Your original exact sequence is just wrong --- you misread the paper you are citing.

Comment: @Sasha what should it be then? It is surely  written $ 0\longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^2 F\longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^2 G\longrightarrow Q\longrightarrow 0 $ with $Q\cong (F\otimes H)\oplus\bigwedge\nolimits^2 H$

Comment: $Q$ is not a direct sum, but an extension, in general nonsplit, see sequence (A.3) in the paper.

Comment: ok, you're saying the direct sum $Q \cong (F\otimes H)\oplus\bigwedge\nolimits^2 H$ is true just localy, right?

Comment: Locally yes, globally no.

Comment: very nice, thanks